# Creating a REST architecture

Tags: rest, architecture, hateoas

What does a true REST architecture looks like ? I mean from a developers perspective what can be done in order to have a true REST Architecture.

So I've read some articles and according to this one [link](https://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html),
there are 4 levels. Well WebApi provides you with the minimum in order to have REST (URI + HTTP verbs). What about The 4th HATEOAS? How would one implement this level, what are some good practices, why is it good to have it?

Are there any other things that a good REST Architecture should have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What does a true REST architecture looks like ?

A true REST architecture looks like the world wide web.

> The REST interface is designed to be efficient for large-grain hypermedia data transfer, optimizing for the common case of the Web -- [Fielding, 2000](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm).

Generic browser communicating with generic servers, using standardized messages and media types.

There's no particular reason that I should be able to use the same client to answer questions on stack overflow that I use to watch funny cat videos, and no particular reason that I should be able to use that same client to search for videos, or shop for books, play chess, read the news, etc.

> Are there any other things that a good REST Architecture should have?

[Hypermedia](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven).  The "HTML" part of the Richardson Maturity Model, and the key element of "hypedmedia as the engine of application state".

The ability to communicate to the client "there is another resource over there, and it understands these standard messages" is a really big deal.